# asp.net mvc views with CLR generics syntax in inherits attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For reasons I won't go into I need to use CLR generics syntax in an ASP.NET MVC view.

I.E. NOT this:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<someobject>
```

but this:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1[[someobject]]
```

When I run the application I get

```
Parser Error: could not load type `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1[[someobject]]`
```

:(

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Aw, come on. Go into the reasons. :)

Comment: because the view is embedded in a class library and ReSharper doesnt recognise the <> syntax without a web.config specifying the page parser filter. This means if i use <> syntax i dont get view intellisense. Crapola!

Comment: @Andrew A view in a class library? I think I need a puke bag. You just threw the cost of your ReSharper license down the drain. :)

Comment: why do you say that? The view is compiled because its part of a plugin.

Comment: @Andrew Well, the puke bag is mostly for the syntax. Are you using this approach? http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins/

Comment: its not that bad, for the sake of regaining intellisense its an acceptible cost, I am doing non-standard stuff. yeah similar approach to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out anything inside the CLR generics syntax needs to be the fully qualified type name. 
I.E it needs the assembly on it:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1[[someobject,myassembly]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just put a web.config in my class library with nothing it in besides the view-engine declarations.  Nothing was hurt from the process.

Comment: What version of resharper? i cant get this to work with 5.1.1